# Swipe actions in UITableViewController not appearing in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, swipe

I want to implement swipe actions in my UITableViewController but doesn't show.

See my code :

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
            let keep = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Profiter"){(UITableViewRowAction,NSIndexPath) -> Void in

                print("hello")
            }

            return [keep]
        }
```

Comment: Having those functions generally works for giving editing to a UITableView. Are you using sectionIndexTitles?  That can throw off the swipe action location, moving it over to the left of the sectionIndexTitles instead of the left of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let keep = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Dude") { action, index in
        print("hello")
    }
    keep.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    return [keep]
}
```

Comment: in fact I disabled the "user interaction" in the parameters of my tableView